# Weird JavaScript syntax I've never used before, but it works

Tags: javascript

Do you know why this code compiles and what is `something`?

```
function Box() {
  something: {
    alert(1);
  }
}

var box = new Box();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a javascript label.

It is used to break or continue nested loops.

Here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

```
// Example code
myLoop:for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        if (whatever)
            break myLoop;
```

Answer (score 9):

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

They are used in combination with `break` and `continue` to choose which loop the statement should apply to when you have nested loops.

It is pointless where it is.